# How to change the damping coefficient of a RevoluteJoint in Drake

Tags: drake

How can we change the damping coefficient of `RevoluteJoint` after calling `parser.AddModelFromFile(urdf_file_name)`?
I believe `damping_` is the variable that I need to change, but there is not setter for this variable: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/838160f3813be33eda8ff42f424b1887076bcbdc/multibody/tree/revolute_joint.h#L121

Should I simply add a setter in `RevoluteJoint` and make a pull request?

To give more background, I want to vary joint damping coefficients for domain randomization (agents are multithreaded), so changing the urdf file wouldn't work in my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We currently have an in progress list of multibody elements (`Joint`, `RigidBody`, etc.) that are set to have their parameters (such as damping) exposed and modifiable. There is a bit more detail to it than just adding a setter, so I'll have to add the feature for you. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/14405) to track the feature request and the resulting pull request. Please feel free to add anything to that issue if you need to.

Comment: Got it. I'll keep an eye on the posted issue.